# tf.keras: How to record gradients during training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am training a tf.keras model and would like to record the gradients during the training.

To be more precise, I want to compute the norm of the gradients for the kernel of each layer at each iteration during the training and write that to a CSV file or something similar.

How do I do that?

I have a partial solution, but am stuck:

1. Write a custom `tf.keras.optimizer` that inherits from an existing optimizer. In that custom optimizer, grab the gradients when they are being computed, and do whatever computations you need to do (in my case: compute their norm for each layer).
2. Now what? In order to actually write these gradients to some file, I need to make sure that the outputs of the ops I added to the custom optimizer are actually getting fetched during the training (using `model.fit()`). How can I do that?
3. Even if the gradient ops I added were evaluated during the training, I still would have to write them to a file somehow. How can I do that?

Or maybe there is a better way?